# На чем лучше разрабатывать приложение под android?

Tags: android

Какой ЯП выбрать?
Просто я новичок и не очень разбираюсь, хочу разрабатывать приложения для андроид, потом игры

Comment: Если приложения то можно посмотреть в сторону Dart/Flutter, для игр Unity или Unreal Engine , но тут надо понимать что там другие ЯП, поэтому лучше сразу определится с тем что хочется и начать с чего-то одного, потому что изучаение даже одного из этих ЯП это минимум год,  да и то если заниматься этим серьёзно.

Answer (score 1):

Разработка приложений и игр несколько разные по своей сути. Начнем с приложений: есть огроменное кол-во [IDE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) и сред разработки которые дают возможность разрабатывать полноценные приложения. На мой взгляд наиболее популярным для разработки приложений является [Android Studio](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) от компании Google, [сайт](https://developer.android.com/studio) где вы ее можете скачать. В этой среде разработки есть огромное кол-во инструментов начиная от редактирования/создания изображений до написания тестов, от создания ссылок на приложение до создания подписанного установщика для выкладывания в Play Market. Это очень удобная и комфортная среда разработки. Так же есть например [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) в которую вы можете напихать кучу плагинов и максимально приблизится к состоянию Android Studio. Есть много плагинов и модулей для достижения этой цели. Так же есть Eclipse за которую я к сожалению ничего не знаю, кроме того что на ней тоже можно разрабатывать приложения. Компания Microsoft тоже имеет продукт для мобильной разработки - [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F). Здесь вы тоже сможете заниматься комфортно разработкой. Все зависит от ваших предпочтений и желаний.

По поводу игр - они насколько я знаю разрабатываются в [Unity 3D](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/s/3d-game-kit) вот ссылка на так называемый Game KIT.

По поводу того на чем писать приложения/игры:

1. Kotlin - довольно молодой язык, которые в последнее время приобретает огромную популярность и получил поддержку от гугла.
2. Java - старожил в мобильной разработке, начинать я бы советовал с изучения этого языка, для того чтобы на котлин было пересесть проще.
3. C# - это тоже язык для разработки приложений и игр (большего к сожалению сказать не могу :( )

Есть куча изданий и туториалов как по созданию приложений так и по созданию игр. Даже тут SO есть вопрос с собранием книг и литературы по данной тематике. Удачи в ваших начинаниях :)

P.S. Многое здесь сказанное - это мое чисто субъективное мнение основанное на личном опыте, просьба критику высказывать в комментариях путем набора текста на клавиатуре а не простого забрасывания минусами.

P.P.S. Если у кого-то есть предложения, просьба указать недостающую информацию в комментариях, дабы я ее смог добавить в ответ.

Comment: А как же Dart/Flutter , на нём можно даже 2D игры писать, хотя для игр лучше сразу браться за Unity или Unreal Engine